# SSIS Package Execution Fails with COM Class Factory and IClassFactory Errors in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm encountering two distinct errors when attempting to manually execute or schedule SSIS packages on my SQL Server 2019. Despite thorough checks on permissions and configurations, these errors persist, preventing any SSIS package from running. I'm seeking insights or solutions to overcome these hurdles.

#### Error 1: COM Class Factory Access Denied

This error comes when the SSIS package is started by the SQL Job with the SQL Server Agent

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {6E8597AE-3486-4838-A8E0-F5C683618DF4} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

#### Error 2: COM Component Instance Creation Failure

This error comes when the SSIS package is manually started from the SSIS catalog.

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {6E8597AE-3486-4838-A8E0-F5C683618DF4} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: c0010014 Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 ; Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0010014;

### Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

- The packages are executed manually over my account or scheduled with the SQL Server Agent.
- The account that tries to execute the packages has the ssis_admin permission and can access the SSISDB.
- I already tried to deploy the package with the target versions 2019 and 2022.

### Questions:

1. What could be causing these access denial and COM component instance creation errors specifically in the context of MSSQL Server 2019 and SSIS packages?
2. Are there known compatibility issues or configurations unique to SQL Server 2019 that might be contributing to these errors?
3. What additional troubleshooting steps or configurations should I consider to resolve these errors and enable the successful execution of SSIS packages?

Comment: 1. `CLSID {...} ` is not helpful as the guid there can provide insight into what specifically you're trying to instantiate. It might be that you're using a custom component built against 2005 API in your package.  2. If the target destination is SQL Server 2019, why would you set the target version in VS to 2022? 3. Do any packages deployed to the server run successfully? 4. What tasks and components are in the package that is failing?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I added the CLISD to my question. @billinkc

Comment: Excellent, your GUID is a SQL Server [DTS runtime wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.wrapper.packageclass?view=sqlserver-2019) As both errors reference this, it smells like a setup or package install issue but there are 3 other questions that may prove enlightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a missing Windows permission for the executing user.

We created a new blank Windows user and a corresponding Proxy User.

Important was den Windows user role that we gave him.